# how to filter based on events that HAVE happened and HAVE NOT happened

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named `orders` in a SQL database that looks like this:

```
    user_id    email            segment    destination    revenue    
    1          joe@smith.com    basic      New York       500
    1          joe@smith.com    luxury     London         750
    1          joe@smith.com    luxury     London         500
    1          joe@smith.com    basic      New York       625
    1          joe@smith.com    basic      Miami          925
    1          joe@smith.com    basic      Los Angeles    218
    1          joe@smith.com    basic      Sydney         200
    2          mary@jones.com   basic      Chicago        375
    2          mary@jones.com   luxury     New York       1500
    2          mary@jones.com   basic      Toronto        2800
    2          mary@jones.com   basic      Miami          750
    2          mary@jones.com   basic      New York       500
    2          mary@jones.com   basic      New York       625
    3          mike@me.com      luxury     New York       650
    3          mike@me.com      basic      New York       875
    4          sally@you.com    luxury     Chicago        1300
    4          sally@you.com    basic      New York       1200
    4          sally@you.com    basic      New York       1000
    4          sally@you.com    luxury     Sydney         725
    5          bob@gmail.com    basic      London         500
    5          bob@gmail.com    luxury     London         750
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22f40a/1

I'd like to be able to apply the following logic to get the final result set:

Return only the distinct `user_id` and the user's `email` based on the following conditions:

1. where `segment` is equal to `luxury` ***and*** `destination` is equal to New York

***OR***

2. where `segment` is equal to `luxury` ***and*** `destination` is equal to `London`

***OR***

3. where `segment` is equal to `basic` ***and*** `destination` is equal to `New York` ***and*** the given user has a `revenue` amount in the `basic` and `New York` records that sums to greater than $2,000

***BUT***

4. a given user has ***not*** previously been to `destination` equal to `Miami`

Based on my sample data, I would like to see the following returned:

```
user_id     email
3           mike@me.com
4           sally@you.com
5           bob@gmail.com
```

I tried to use the following to get ***part*** of what I need:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT(user_id),
   email
FROM orders o

WHERE
(o.segment = 'luxury' AND o.destination = 'New York')
OR
(o.segment = 'luxury' AND o.destination = 'London')
```

But, this query doesn't handle conditions #3 and #4 above.  I feel like a window function might be helpful here, but I don't know quite how to implement it.

If someone could help me with this query, I would be incredibly grateful!

Thanks!

Comment: First question. What DB are you using?

Comment: Second. Use a subquery to get all users that have `destination = Miami` and use that to filter out the users

Comment: I'm using Postgres version 14.

Comment: @drum -- would you suggest using a subquery or a CTE?  Perhaps use a CTE to get `destination = Miami`, then join this back to the original data using some sort of indicator and finally filter on the indicator?  Something like this?

Comment: subqueries and ctes are the same. whatever you want for your readability. and you can use them directly in your WHERE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use subqueries to achieve what you need:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT(o.user_id),
   o.email
FROM orders o
WHERE
  (
    -- Clause 1
    (o.segment = 'luxury' AND o.destination = 'New York')
    OR
    -- Clause 2
    (o.segment = 'luxury' AND o.destination = 'London')
    OR
    -- Clause 3
    (o.user_id IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT(o.user_id)
      FROM orders o
      WHERE o.segment = 'basic' AND o.destination = 'New York'
      GROUP BY o.user_id, o.email, o.segment, o.destination
      HAVING SUM(o.revenue) > 2000
    ))
  )
  AND
  -- Clause 4
  o.user_id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(o.user_id)
    FROM orders o
    WHERE o.destination = 'Miami'
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

here's another to do it by scanning the table once, `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT user_id, email,
       SUM(case
          when segment='luxury' and destination in ('New York','London') then 1 
          else 0 
       end) as is_luxury,
       SUM(case
          when segment='basic' and destination in ('New York') then 1
          else 0
       end) as is_basic,       
       SUM(case
          when segment='basic' and destination in ('New York') then revenue
          else 0
       end) as basic_revenue,
       SUM(case when destination in ('Miami') then 1 else 0 end) as is_miami
FROM orders
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING (is_luxury > 0 OR (is_basic > 0 AND basic_revenue > 2000))
  AND NOT is_miami;
```